# Syncfusion SfDataGrid crashing when using SummaryRow and Grouping

Tags: c#, ios, datagrid, xamarin.ios, syncfusion

I am using a Syncfusion Xamarin.iOS library component SfDataGrid in an iOS application.

I am making use of the Grouping and SummaryRow features of the datagrid to create custom grouping header text message. In my solution this works without any issues in debug mode, when I run the application in release mode the Syncfusion component crashes with the following error getting logged in my hockeyapp crash logs:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No method 'OfType' exists on type 'System.Linq.Queryable'.

at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.FindMethod (System.Type type, System.String methodName, System.Type[] typeArgs, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression[] args, System.Reflection.BindingFlags flags) <0x100bed560 + 0x00178> in <7e733344809544cdb96fb85d3fa04558#6766c6796a86a13adfcc8378724365f2>:0 
  at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call (System.Type type, System.String methodName, System.Type[] typeArguments, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression[] arguments) <0x100beccb0 + 0x00083> in <7e733344809544cdb96fb85d3fa04558#6766c6796a86a13adfcc8378724365f2>:0 
  at Syncfusion.Data.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.OfType (System.Linq.IQueryable source, System.Type sourceType) <0x100f6ac80 + 0x00103> in <8945d0bafa9a4425bcee03773220107f#6766c6796a86a13adfcc8378724365f2>:0 
  at Syncfusion.Data.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.OfQueryable (System.Collections.IEnumerable items, System.Type sourceType) <0x100f6a820 + 0x0001f> in <8945d0bafa9a4425bcee03773220107f#6766c6796a86a13adfcc8378724365f2>:0 
  at Syncfusion.Data.TopLevelGroup.UpdateCaptionSummaryForBottomLevelGroup (Syncfusion.Data.Group group, Syncfusion.Data.ISummaryRow summaryRow) <0x100f53260 + 0x001a7> in <8945d0bafa9a4425bcee03773220107f#6766c6796a86a13adfcc8378724365f2>:0 
  at Syncfusion.Data.TopLevelGroup.UpdateCaptionSummaries (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] groups, System.Int32 level, Syncfusion.Data.ISummaryRow summaryRow) <0x100f52070 + 0x000af> in <8945d0bafa9a4425bcee03773220107f#6766c6796a86a13adfcc8378724365f2>:0 
  at Syncfusion.Data.TopLevelGroup.UpdateCaptionSummaries (Syncfusion.Data.Group group, System.Int32 level, Syncfusion.Data.ISummaryRow summaryRow) <0x100f51f90 + 0x00063> in <8945d0bafa9a4425bcee03773220107f#6766c6796a86a13adfcc8378724365f2>:0 
  at Syncfusion.Data.TopLevelGroup.UpdateCaptionSummaries () <0x100f51e50 + 0x0009f> in <8945d0bafa9a4425bcee03773220107f#6766c6796a86a13adfcc8378724365f2>:0 
  at Syncfusion.Data.CollectionViewAdv.InitializeTopLevelGroup () <0x100f34790 + 0x001ab> in <8945d0bafa9a4425bcee03773220107f#6766c6796a86a13adfcc8378724365f2>:0 
  at Syncfusion.Data.CollectionViewAdv.RefreshTopLevelGroup () <0x100f349e0 + 0x00043> in <8945d0bafa9a4425bcee03773220107f#6766c6796a86a13adfcc8378724365f2>:0 
  at Syncfusion.Data.CollectionViewAdv.EndDeferInternal () <0x100f306a0 + 0x001f3> in <8945d0bafa9a4425bcee03773220107f#6766c6796a86a13adfcc8378724365f2>:0 
  at Syncfusion.Data.CollectionViewAdv.EndDefer () <0x100f30660 + 0x0001f> in <8945d0bafa9a4425bcee03773220107f#6766c6796a86a13adfcc8378724365f2>:0 
  at Syncfusion.Data.CollectionViewAdv+DeferHelper.Dispose (System.Boolean isDisposing) <0x100f3a8a0 + 0x0003b> in <8945d0bafa9a4425bcee03773220107f#6766c6796a86a13adfcc8378724365f2>:0 
  at Syncfusion.Data.CollectionViewAdv+DeferHelper.Dispose () <0x100f3a860 + 0x0001f> in <8945d0bafa9a4425bcee03773220107f#6766c6796a86a13adfcc8378724365f2>:0 
  at Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.SfDataGrid.DeferRefresh () <0x100e65750 + 0x000f3> in <9c1c4744d92347f39b995b2a4b95a8bb#6766c6796a86a13adfcc8378724365f2>:0 
  at Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.SfDataGrid.SetSourceList (System.Object source) <0x100e639b0 + 0x00033> in <9c1c4744d92347f39b995b2a4b95a8bb#6766c6796a86a13adfcc8378724365f2>:0 
  at Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.SfDataGrid.RefreshContainerAndView () <0x100e66f60 + 0x00043> in <9c1c4744d92347f39b995b2a4b95a8bb#6766c6796a86a13adfcc8378724365f2>:0 
  at Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.SfDataGrid.gridLoaded () <0x100e637d0 + 0x0014f> in <9c1c4744d92347f39b995b2a4b95a8bb#6766c6796a86a13adfcc8378724365f2>:0 
  at Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.SfDataGrid.LayoutSubviews () <0x100e602a0 + 0x00033> in <9c1c4744d92347f39b995b2a4b95a8bb#6766c6796a86a13adfcc8378724365f2>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) <0x10050b6f0 + 0x0002b> in <cc077ba5ca594b7b8b31455dce914ca4#6766c6796a86a13adfcc8378724365f2>:0 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) <0x10050b630 + 0x000ab> in <cc077ba5ca594b7b8b31455dce914ca4#6766c6796a86a13adfcc8378724365f2>:0
```

To troubleshoot this further I tried to test my code on the sample application provided by syncfusion in the Grouping.cs sample (NOTE: in this usage I am enabling SummaryRow updates in the GridLoaded handler so that the Grouping Summary Rows reflect dynamic changes to the underlying datasource):

```
public Grouping ()
{
    this.SfGrid = new SfDataGrid ();
    this.SfGrid.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Single;
    this.SfGrid.ItemsSource = new GroupingViewModel ().ProductDetails;
    this.SfGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn += GridAutoGenerateColumns;
    this.SfGrid.GroupColumnDescriptions.Add (new GroupColumnDescription (){ ColumnName = "Product" });
    this.SfGrid.HeaderRowHeight = 45;
    this.SfGrid.RowHeight = 45;
    this.SfGrid.AllowGroupExpandCollapse = true;
    this.SfGrid.QueryRowHeight += SfGrid_QueryRowHeight;


    var summaryRow = new GridSummaryRow();
    summaryRow.Title = "    {Key} ({ProductCount}) {TotalPrice}";
    summaryRow.ShowSummaryInRow = true;
    summaryRow.SummaryColumns.Add(new GridSummaryColumn
    {
        Name = "TotalPrice",
        MappingName = "Price",
        Format = "{Sum:n}",
        SummaryType = SummaryType.DoubleAggregate
    });
    summaryRow.SummaryColumns.Add(new GridSummaryColumn
    {
        Name = "ProductCount",
        MappingName = "ProductType",
        Format = "{Count}",
        SummaryType = SummaryType.CountAggregate
    });
    this.SfGrid.CaptionSummaryRow = summaryRow;
    // enable summary row update
    this.SfGrid.GridLoaded += (object sender, GridLoadedEventArgs e) =>
    {
        if (this.SfGrid.View != null)
            this.SfGrid.View.LiveDataUpdateMode = LiveDataUpdateMode.AllowSummaryUpdate;
    };

    this.AddSubview (SfGrid);
}
```

This test however crashes the app even in debug mode with this piece of code:

```
var summaryRow = new GridSummaryRow();
summaryRow.Title = "    {Key} ({ProductCount}) {TotalPrice}";
summaryRow.ShowSummaryInRow = true;
summaryRow.SummaryColumns.Add(new GridSummaryColumn
{
    Name = "TotalPrice",
    MappingName = "Price",
    Format = "{Sum:n}",
    SummaryType = SummaryType.DoubleAggregate
});
summaryRow.SummaryColumns.Add(new GridSummaryColumn
{
    Name = "ProductCount",
    MappingName = "ProductType",
    Format = "{Count}",
    SummaryType = SummaryType.CountAggregate
});
this.SfGrid.CaptionSummaryRow = summaryRow;
// enable summary row update
this.SfGrid.GridLoaded += (object sender, GridLoadedEventArgs e) =>
{
    if (this.SfGrid.View != null)
        this.SfGrid.View.LiveDataUpdateMode = LiveDataUpdateMode.AllowSummaryUpdate;
};
```

It is very possible that this is a broken feature in the component and I already submitted a ticket with Syncfusion to investigate it, but if anyone has experience working with this component and using the features I am trying to use successfully it would be very helpful to get some input.

### UPDATE:

The initial error I was seeing was in fact fixed with the use of a linker skip flag for Release and Debug Device builds.

Setting Project Options > Build > iOS Build > Additional mtouch arguments (for Release/iPhone and Debug/iPhone targets) to `--linkskip=System.Core`

This resolved the "No method 'OfType' exists on type 'System.Linq.Queryable'" error I was seeing.

---

This fix uncovered another Syncfusion library error however:

```
Message: ColumnName cannot be NULL
Source: Syncfusion.Linq.iOS
StackTrace:
  at Syncfusion.Data.Extensions.PropertyDescriptorExtensions.GetPropertyDescriptor (System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptorCollection pdc, System.String columnName) [0x00003] in <6f9d653653de4429a0f62ab48bee8a99>:0 
  at Syncfusion.Data.TopLevelGroup.UpdateCaptionSummaryForGroup (Syncfusion.Data.Group group, Syncfusion.Data.ISummaryRow summaryRow) [0x00246] in <6f9d653653de4429a0f62ab48bee8a99>:0 
  at Syncfusion.Data.TopLevelGroup.UpdateCaptionSummaries (Syncfusion.Data.Group group, System.Int32 level, Syncfusion.Data.ISummaryRow summaryRow) [0x00009] in <6f9d653653de4429a0f62ab48bee8a99>:0 
  at Syncfusion.Data.TopLevelGroup.UpdateCaptionSummaries () [0x00044] in <6f9d653653de4429a0f62ab48bee8a99>:0 
  at Syncfusion.Data.CollectionViewAdv.InitializeTopLevelGroup () [0x0006a] in <6f9d653653de4429a0f62ab48bee8a99>:0 
  at Syncfusion.Data.CollectionViewAdv.RefreshTopLevelGroup () [0x00022] in <6f9d653653de4429a0f62ab48bee8a99>:0 
  at Syncfusion.Data.CollectionViewAdv.EndDeferInternal () [0x0008c] in <6f9d653653de4429a0f62ab48bee8a99>:0 
  at Syncfusion.Data.CollectionViewAdv.EndDefer () [0x00008] in <6f9d653653de4429a0f62ab48bee8a99>:0 
  at Syncfusion.Data.CollectionViewAdv+DeferHelper.Dispose (System.Boolean isDisposing) [0x00014] in <6f9d653653de4429a0f62ab48bee8a99>:0 
  at Syncfusion.Data.CollectionViewAdv+DeferHelper.Dispose () [0x00000] in <6f9d653653de4429a0f62ab48bee8a99>:0 
  at Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.SfDataGrid.DeferRefresh () [0x00050] in <c3adc0ba74224f2691c435bf11ff9990>:0 
  at Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.SfDataGrid.SetSourceList (System.Object source) [0x0000d] in <c3adc0ba74224f2691c435bf11ff9990>:0 
  at Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.SfDataGrid.RefreshContainerAndView () [0x00026] in <c3adc0ba74224f2691c435bf11ff9990>:0 
  at Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.SfDataGrid.gridLoaded () [0x00077] in <c3adc0ba74224f2691c435bf11ff9990>:0 
  at Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.SfDataGrid.LayoutSubviews () [0x00008] in <c3adc0ba74224f2691c435bf11ff9990>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3985/35d1ccd0/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3985/35d1ccd0/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 
  at SampleBrowser.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in /Users/dsamuylov/Documents/Syncfusion/15.1451.0.37/Xamarin/sample/iOS/SampleBrowser/Main.cs:19
```

### Solution

After additional input from +1 Vimal Prabhu I have realized that the reason for this problem is that the Syncfusion SfDataGrid is using reflection. By default in release mode iOS apps go through linking process which uses static analysis to figure out all the possible used code paths and removes all of the unused code but this process can not follow the paths created dynamically at runtime using reflection, so if you use any kind of linking on your project some of SfDataGrid's features as in my case will not work and cause crashes.

Short explanation. Turn off linking in your release build:

`Project Options > Build > iOS Build > Linker behavior: "Don't Link"`

### Conclusion

If you want to use full set of features in SfDataGrid you won't be able to use Linking on your release build. In my case this increased the size of the release application by 50%, from 40mb to 60mb. In my case this is a not a significant problem (enterprise deployed app internal company use), for an AppStore app that is much larger in size this could be a significant and prohibitive change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your facing is possibly a known Xamarin framework issue that occurs when the linker mode is set as LinkFrameWorkSDK’s . Try the steps mentioned in the following KB link.

KB Link : https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/5986/how-to-solve-system-methodmissingexception-in-xamarin-forms-ios-when-using-sfdatagrid

Please don’t get confused that the above KB link directs to Xamarin.Forms platform instead of Xamarin.iOS. Fortunately the issue and the solution are the same for both the Xamarin.Forms.iOS and the Xamarin.iOS platforms.

If you are able to reproduce the issue even after trying the steps mentioned in the KB, kindly revert us with a replicating sample of the same so that we can resolve your issue the soonest and help you better.

Refer this UG that contains detailed description about all the possible formatting, aggregates, custom summaries etc of the summary row along with a sample

UG Link : https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin-ios/sfdatagrid/summary#formatting-summary

Comment: +1 The first link helped resolve the initial error. The second link doesn't provided a working version of usage of the Grouping feature of the DataGrid with updates enabled on the CaptionSummary rows to reflect changes to the underlying DataSource. See UPDATED: part in the original question about a new error that is still being thrown by the Syncfusion component. Is this a configuration/usage error on my part or a bug within the library?

Comment: Marking this as the answer since the information I received from Vimal helped me understand the problem and find a fix, see above SOLUTION: section for the final fix